# Priority ceiling protocol in ERCOSek RTOS?

Tags: rtos

can anyone please explain practical usage of stack based priority ceiling protocol in ERCOSek(Automotive standard RTOS) RTOS? This protocol concept is an alternative to semaphore used in other commercial RTOS. As i heard that this one is solving the problem of priority inversion,so i would like know how to make use of this in application software.. Thank you in advance.....

Answer (score 1):

Dr. Kalinsky explains all these concepts (priority inversion, priority inheritance, and priority ceiling) in the paper "Mutexes Battle Priority Inversions" at http://www.kalinskyassociates.com/Wpaper2.html.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but this not an answer, but comment